# Rails Activerecord: jsonb attributes readed as string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm saving some picture exit in my db. The column is a jsonb data type.

To save the exif I use carrierwave

```
def store_exif
    if file && model
      begin
        exif = Exif::Data.new(IO.read(file.path))[:exif].to_h
        exif.delete(:maker_note)
        model.exif = exif.to_json
      rescue
      end
    end
  end
```

When I read the attributes the type is string.

```
p.exif
=> "{\"exposure_time\":\"1/4\",\"fnumber\":\"8/5\",\"exposure_program\":2,\"iso_speed_ratings\":1250,\"exif_version\":\"0231\",\"date_time_original\":\"2020:10:04 21:42:05\",\"components_configuration\":\"\\u0001\\u0002\\u0003\\u0000\",\"shutter_speed_value\":\"61506/32255\",\"aperture_value\":\"14447/10653\",\"brightness_value\":\"-42954/7669\",\"exposure_bias_value\":\"-15/256\",\"metering_mode\":5,\"flash\":16,\"focal_length\":\"21/5\",\"subject_area\":0,\"color_space\":65535,\"pixel_x_dimension\":4032,\"pixel_y_dimension\":3024,\"sensing_method\":2,\"scene_type\":\"\\u0001\",\"custom_rendered\":8,\"exposure_mode\":0,\"white_balance\":0,\"scene_capture_type\":0,\"flash_pix_version\":\"0100\"}"

p.exif.class
=> String
```

Why?? I need an hash with my attributes...

Comment: When using native JSON columns you should leave the casting to the database driver. This is a classic double encoding issue that occurs whenever people think that manually JSON encoding is a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exif.to_json` gives you a string. Just save `exif` as it is as a hash:  `model.exif = exif`. Rails and Postgres will do the job.